# How to Install an Older Version of Bazel using Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, bazel

I tried to install an older version of Bazel using homebrew by specifying the commit I need (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/homebrew-tap/c8a0ccc2a8b442d9887d88c6380f835f533ffd47/Formula/bazel.rb).

I used the command `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bazelbuild/homebrew-tap/c8a0ccc2a8b442d9887d88c6380f835f533ffd47/Formula/bazel.rb`. However, it points to the Homebrew core instead of the Bazel tap.

Has anyone used brew to manage Bazel version? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it points to the Homebrew core instead of the Bazel tap"? This command works for me; it does use the formula in the URL and not the core one.

Comment: Not a Mac person, so this is somewhat tangential, but perhaps still helpful: If depending on specific version(s) of bazel, you may want to consider [`bazelisk`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk) to handle your requirements independent of host setup.

Comment: Same here. I am stuck at this point. HomeBrew's lates (Bazel 1.2.0) cannot build TensorFlow for me, rather I am being told to downgrade to 1.1.0. The suggested downgrade method which the OP has stated does not work

Answer (score 28):

```
brew tap bazelbuild/tap
brew extract bazel bazelbuild/tap --version 3.1.0
brew install bazel@3.1.0
```

That should do.

Comment: If you get build errors on last step, it's likely because you need to accept xcode license agreement `sudo xcodebuild -license`

Comment: No build errors on the last step, but after it finishes, the bazel@3.1.0 folder created in my Cellar folder disappears and the package does not appear anywhere in my homebrew packages

Comment: Also, supposing it had worked, how could I call this version from the command line with the new naming scheme ? Is there a way for me to just call bazel instead of having to call bazel@3.1.0 from the command line ? (specify a default version that isnt the latest one )

Answer (score 1):

For ex: to install bazel 1.1.0

```
$ wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/1.1.0/bazel-1.1.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
$ chmod +x bazel-1.1.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
$ ./bazel-1.1.0-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
```

Comment: Note: Don't forget to add the path into /etc/paths or your bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

We can try this command to install bazel 3.7.2:

```
cd "/usr/local/lib/bazel/bin" && curl -fLO https://releases.bazel.build/3.7.2/release/bazel-3.7.2-darwin-x86_64 && chmod +x bazel-3.7.2-darwin-x86_64
```